# Interactive Powershell Script to Return Logon Account Validity Value

Tags: powershell, active-directory

```
Function Test-ADAuthentication {
param($username,$password)
(new-object directoryservices.directoryentry "",$username,$password).psbase.name -ne $null

}

    $username = read-host "Please Enter Username";
    $password = read-host "Please Enter Password" -assecurestring;



        Test-ADAuthentication $username $password;

                Start-Sleep -s 5
```

Does Anybody know why this function at the top works on it's own but doesnt work when ran like the above? I am guessing it's the order in which things execute so, how can i change the variables to have the input information in them first to get the correct boolean result?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean under "works on it's own"?

Comment: And what is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: The `DirectoryEntry` constructor expects the password in cleartext - not a `SecureString`

Comment: It works as a function, but the bit in the middle i added to make it interactive returns a value of false on my username and password, I am given sets of usernames and passwords - service accounts or as such, if i have problems with a service, this can eliminate it being a wrong password as i can check, there are multiple child domains etc and AD is managed by a service management company, but i can still poll their AD to get this info so, this would be highly beneficial. If nobody knows how to acheive this then i will keep thinking how. Thanks

Comment: Mathias R Jessen provided the correct answer on why it returned the wrong value. Thanks